# Two IF statements in one formula

Tags: excel-formula

I am creating an excel table for the MLS and I am having trouble when there is a draw as it is automatically defined as false and given a zero value when I need the result to be a 1.

```
=IF($S3>$R3, 3, 0)
```

So this is what I started with, where R3 is home and S3 is away, for the away points total.
What I need is for `value_if_false` to equal something along the lines of IF($S3=$R3, 1)

I came up with `=IF($S3>$R3, 3, (($S3=$R3), 1, 0))`

Any help would be appreciated,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is achieved via a nested `if`:

```
=IF($S3>$R3,3,(IF($S3=$R3,1,0)))
```